# login to root user with password inside script only

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, sudo, root

I want to write a shell script that can login to root user and it should carry password inside the same script. It should not ask for password on the terminal.

I have written a script that works fine, but it is asking for password on the terminal, I want to automate this process by giving the password inside script only.

```
id
sudo -s <<EOF
echo Now i am root
id
mkdir someDir
whoami
EOF
```

note: i want to get it done without touching /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: You can use `expect` for that

Comment: Please note that writing the root password into a file (and without file encryption) is a big security risk!  Any program started by you can read that file.

Comment: @annahri can you please provide an example. I have tried to use `expect` like this ```spawn ./c.sh

expect "[sudo] password for divyaa:\r"

send -- "mypass\r"

expect eof
```  but its giving this error ```spawn ./c.sh
invalid command name "sudo"
    while executing
"sudo"
    invoked from within
"expect "[sudo] password for divyas:\r""
    (file "./a.sh" line 7)
```

Comment: @Ned64 thanku for the information. i will keep this mind, for now there is a need to do this.

Comment: Do not put so much code in a comment (because it is difficult to read). Add it to your question instead and mention that in a comment.

Comment: Usually I hate when ppl tell me alternative ways to do my goal, but this just seems plain wrong. Something is incorrect, there has to be a better way than scripting roots pwd. Heck use ssh root@localhost and RSA keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to automate this process by giving the password inside script only.

```
id
echo your_password_here |sudo --stdin bash -c "
echo Now i am root
id
mkdir someDir
whoami
"
```

`man sudo` :

```
 -S, --stdin
             Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input in‐
             stead of using the terminal device.
```

Comment: Why the `{  }` braces?

Comment: No warning about how bad an idea this is? There has to be a better way. Create a specific user or use ssh via RSA, something!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Could add it as answer?