# Error: su: must be run from a terminal

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, su

When I try to login to root user using shell script given below, it throws an error:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

The srcipt (`scriptfile.sh`) looks as follows:

```
su -s <<EOF
echo Now i am root
whoami
EOF
```

Although I can successfully do `su` from the terminal, it logs in to the root user by default.

**FYI**: Same script is working fine when we replace `su` with `sudo`.
I am running this script as normal user, not as root.

What can be the possible reason for the error and how can I solve this?

Note: I want to get it done without touching `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [login to root user with password inside script only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594245/login-to-root-user-with-password-inside-script-only)

Comment: No. Its a different question entirely. I didn't ask this question over there to avoid mixing up of two topics. If you look into the scripts carefully you will find a very big difference, one uses sudo and the the other uses su. With sudo its working fine, but with su its not. Question has been edited for more clarification

Comment: Why are you using `-s`? What are you trying to achieve with this command? Aren't you getting an `su: option requires an argument -- 's'` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite likely something down to syntax/interactive shell from what I googled so far, but I am no expert!

Below works for me, even if technically su should not be used in a shell script, sudo is more secure.

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec su root --command 'echo -e "hello world" >> "/home/parallels/rootWasHere.txt"'
```

And so does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

runAsRoot="
printf \"\nhey there\n\"
printf \"\nhello world, I am root\n\" >> \"/home/parallels/rootWasHere.txt\"
"
exec su root -c "$runAsRoot"
```

Also, in regards to -s option for su, that specifies only the shell according to the manual. This doesn't imply that it will also execute what's passed afterwards/ to -s, so I think you could something on the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

runAsRoot="
printf \"\nhey there\n\"
printf \"\nhello world, I am root and my shell is \$SHELL\n\" >> \"/home/parallels/rootWasHere.txt\"
"
exec su root -s /bin/zsh -c "$runAsRoot"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from https://netsec.ws/?p=337,

```
python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/sh")'

echo os.system('/bin/bash')

/bin/sh -i

perl —e 'exec "/bin/sh";'

perl: exec "/bin/sh";

ruby: exec "/bin/sh"

lua: os.execute('/bin/sh')

(From within IRB) exec "/bin/sh"

(From within vi) :!bash

(From within vi) :set shell=/bin/bash:shell

(From within nmap) !sh
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.

Answer (score -5):

You can add the following to your shell

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Comment: Its not working. I have also checked env is set properly.

Comment: Please elaborate